# Center text with label in stacklayout with nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I would like to know how can I center a text with label textwrap in stack layout please.

I tried with horizontalAlignment="center", it's ok with small text (example: "hello", "test test"), but if I use textWrap on label it doesn't work...

```
<StackLayout v-for="(text, indexVerse) in texts"
                borderRadius="5" margin="5" padding="15" row="1" col="0" horizontalAlignment="center">

    <Label textWrap="true"
            :text="text.content"
            color="#FFFFFF"
            textAlign="center"
            fontSize="20"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The texts are set on the left and no center :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property to set text alignment is `textAlignment` if its inline on the template and `text-align` if you are setting it through css.

Try replacing `textAlign` with `textAlignment` like the following:

```html
<Label textWrap="true"
            :text="text.content"
            color="#FFFFFF"
            textAlignment="center"
            fontSize="20"/>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thx @William !